# Saving a CheckBox value to SQL Database table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a checkbox value in ASP.NET to save to a database.

Now the field type in SQL Server, I remember years ago using Boolean, but that's not there under SQL Server 2008 r2.

What to use now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type "Bit" is what you are looking for.

Per MSDN: "An integer data type that can take a value of 1, 0, or NULL."

Use value of 1 for true, 0 for false.

[MSDN Info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correct then.... bit is the type you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

BIT or tinyint. They take up the same space on disk - 1 byte, bit can be 0 or 1.